# Is there any way to apply a length of a string to a size of an array in C language?

Tags: c

I have a string `x` and an array `x_integer`.
String `x` has a length of `8`, but when I use the length to initialize the array
`int x_integer[strlen(x)] = {0}`, it doesn't allow me to do that since it needs constant value.
So are there anyways that I can take the length of string `x` and use that for the array besides using `#define SIZE 8` cause my string changes each time.

Comment: Is `x_integer` defined inside of a function or outside at file scope?

Comment: 1) Is the string a _string literal_ like `"abc"`?  2) Are you looking to initialize the elements to something other than 0?

Comment: The string is a binary number, and I want to convert it to a array of integers holding those numbers

Answer (score 2):

VLAs can't be initialized.

Use `strlen` inside of the subscript operator inside of the definition first:

```
int x_integer[strlen(x)];
```

and then, if wanted, you need to initialize each element of `x_integer` on its own:

```
int len_x = strlen(x);
for ( int i = 0; i < len_x; i++ )
{
    x_integer[i] = 0;
}
```

---

Test code ([Online example](https://godbolt.org/z/8TPz8K)):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
//#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main (void) 
{  
    const char *x = "Hello"; 
    int x_integer[strlen(x)];

    int len_x = strlen(x);
    for ( int i = 0; i < len_x; i++ )
    {
        x_integer[i] = 0;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < len_x; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d\n", x_integer[i]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./a.out
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: This one does not work. Since x_integer[strlen(x)] will prompt the fault that the expression needs to be constant value.

Comment: `will prompt the fault that the expression needs to be constant value` You have to use a compatible compiler that supports [variable length arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays). If your compiler doesn't support them, you can't use them. @KhangNguyen Please share what compiler, compiler version and compiler options are you using.

Comment: @KhangNguyen Then maybe your compiler doesn't support the use of VLAs. Note that after C99 not every C implementation need to support it. It worked when I did it. I added an example and you can see online that it works. Check if the macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__` is defined on your compiler. If it is, your compiler doesn't have the VLA extension.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in C to initialise the custom/variable length arrays.

But you can always make use of `malloc()` and `calloc()` to allocate the requested memory.

For your use case, `calloc()` fits the best as it sets the allocated memory to `0`.

**Also, after performing operations, don't forget to carry out a proper memory management.**

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char* x = "test string";

    int* x_integer = (int*)calloc(strlen(x), sizeof(int));

    //Perform operation

    //Memory management
    free(x_integer);

    return 0;
}
```